# which one of these proofs more acceptable for $A⊆B$ iff $A\cap B=A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I've got two answers to prove that $A⊆B$ iff $A\cap B=A$

first,

> (*) Assume that $A\cap B=A$. If $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ $\rightarrow $ $x\in (A\cap B)$. And if $y\in B$ but $y\notin A$ $\rightarrow $ $y\in (B-A)$. Therefore $x,y\in B$ and $x\in A$ but $y\notin A$, which shows that $A⊆B$.
>
> (**) Assume that $A⊆B$. If $x,y\in B$ and $x\in A$ but $y\notin A$ $\rightarrow $ $x\in (A\cap B)$ and $y\in (B-A)$. Since $(A\cap B)$ has the same element as $A$, which is $x$, then $A\cap B=A$.

second,

> (*) Assume that $A\cap B=A$. If $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ $\rightarrow$ $x\in (A\cap B)$. In particular, $x\in B$. This proves that $A⊆B$.
>
> (**) Assume that $A⊆B$. If $x\in (A\cap B)$ $\rightarrow$ $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, so in particular $x\in A$. This proves that $A\cap B⊆A$. Now if $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ $\rightarrow$ $x\in (A\cap B)$. This proves that $A⊆A\cap B$. Together this implies that $A=A\cap B$.

Which one of these proofs more acceptable and why? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: A problem with your reasoning is that you prove each time exactly what you have assumed. F.e. in second $(*)$ you assume that $x \in B$ (If $x\in A$ and $x \in B$...) and then you conclude that $x \in B$ (in particular $x\in B$)!! That does not prove that $A \subset B$ in any way. That is also the case in first $(*)$ but there it is a little more vague. To be clear, I do not think that what you have is wrong but you could improve your phrasing and make more clear. Your implications should also become more evident (in my opinion).

Comment: I can't make heads or tails with the first $(*)$. In the first $(**)$ you seem to be using what you want to prove when you say that $A\cap B$ has the same elements as $A$.

Answer (score 4):

Your first proof approach is dealing with two distinct arbitrary elements of (fill in the blank). This is not necessary or useful. It seems moreover that you misunderstand the purpose of an arbitrary element. (I will try to explain this further, but first, I will address your second attempt.)

Your second proof attempt avoids this issue, but still fails to complete either section of the proof. In (*), you have only proved that $A\cap B\subseteq B.$ In (**), you have proved that $A\cap B\subseteq A,$ but have failed to prove that $A\subseteq A\cap B.$

---

In general, one way to show that $C\subseteq D$ for some sets $C$ and $D$ is to show that for any $x,$ if $x\in C$, then $x\in D.$ Your second proof fell apart in assuming too much. Let me break it down for you.

> (*) Assume that $A∩B=A.$

Good start. Now we need to suppose that $x$ is some element of $A$....

> If $x∈A$  and $x∈B$

Oh, no! You just assumed that $x$ was an element of $A\cap B$! True, that happens to be equal to $A,$ but you're still skipping a step. Instead, we start by assuming $x\in A.$ Since $A=A\cap B$ by assumption, then we can *conclude* that...

> $x∈(A∩B)$. In particular, $x∈B.$

*Now* we're done with that part.

> (**) Assume that $A⊆B.$ If $x∈(A∩B)  →  x∈A$  and $x∈B$, so in particular $x∈A$. This proves that $A∩B⊆A$.

Doing fine so far. Now we need to prove that $A\subseteq A\cap B,$ so we start by assuming that $x$ is some element of $A$....

> Now if $x∈A$  and $x∈B$

Again, we run into the same problem! Instead, assume only that $x\in A.$ Since $A\subseteq B,$ then we can *conclude* that $x\in B.$ So, since $x\in A$ and $x\in B,$ then....

> $x∈(A∩B)$. This proves that $A⊆A∩B$. Together this implies that $A=A∩B$.

---

The reason for the arbitrary element is so that we don't have to make a different argument for every single element. (There could be infinitely many, so we might never get done!) Instead, we use a sort of "blanket argument" that applies to every element of the given set at once (even/especially if the given set is empty). There is really no need (or use) for the $y$ (that I can see). Perhaps you've seen a proof that used $x$ and $y$ in a way that seems similar to you. If this is the case, please let me know, and I'll try to make clear the distinctions and utility of such an approach.

Comment: what a very kind of you, sir! I need time to grasp it, btw thank you so much! this is my very first time in learning real analysis & gotta learn it harder

Comment: Take your time! If there's any aspect that you're having trouble with--or even if you think you've got it, and just want to double-check--feel free to let me know, and I'll try to clear things up. Happy pondering!

Comment: Very complete answer! I would add that many mathematicians consider that using logical symbol  like  $→$ in a sentence is ugly and you should use one of the numerous logical connectors there are in English: so, then, as a consequence,....

Comment: Good point, @Taladris.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part, the first proof contains a completely irrelevant part. Who cares about that $y$? All you have to show is that if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$. There's nothing about any $y\in B-A$.

The second proof is fairly okay, as Git Gud indicates in the comments, writing "$x\in A$ and $x\in B\to x\in A\cap B$" is not what you want to show. You want to take $x\in A$, and deduce that it is in $B$; for this you need to use the assumption that $A=A\cap B$, and therefore if $x\in A$ then $x\in A\cap B$, and so on.

The second part is also strange in the first proof. I'm not clear as to the role $y$ plays there as well. In addition, the fact that $A\cap B$ and $A$ have the same elements is exactly what you have to prove, you can't make an appeal to this.

In the second part's proof of the second part, in the second inclusion ($A\subseteq A\cap B$ part), you're not really proving what needs to be proved either. But it's much closer to an actual proof. You need to take an element from $A$ and show it is in $A\cap B$. You instead take an element in the intersection, then you claim it is in the intersection.

In short, the first proof of both part would have probably got no points from me; whereas the second proof would get about 50% of the grade in its current form.

Comment: I can't possibly agree that "Assume that $A\cap B=A$. If $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ $\rightarrow$ $x\in (A\cap B)$. In particular, $x\in B$" is fine.

Comment: Git Gud, it might not be fine in the level of a research mathematician. But in the level of a very intro of set theory, I'd give it a full grade (more or less). I do agree that it implicitly omits taking an element from $A$, and the arrow is reversed. I'll clarify on that.

Comment: I'm not even sure of what the OP is trying to convey, but even if the arrow was in the right direction, I'd still nitpick (?) about the difference between saying "$x\in A\cap B\to x\in A$ and $x\in B$" and "If $x\in A\cap B$, then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$". My point being that the first version says that the conditional statement $x\in A\cap B\to x\in A$ holds. Mathematics is to be parsed with priority over natural language.

Comment: Git Gud, yes I also tell that to my students repeatedly over the first couple of weeks of the semester (and I will tell them that again two weeks from now, when the first class begins). But in general I'm willing to look the other way if someone does that. It's a bad habit, but it's not the worst.

Comment: i also need time to grasp it, sir. btw thank you so much! you're very kind! @AsafKaragila

Answer (score 3):

Trim the fat.    You don't need to worry about elements not in $A$ but in $B$ (your '$y$').   You just need to worry about all of the elements that are in $A$ and whether or not they are in $B$ and/or the intersection.

I also prefer not mixing words and symbols as much as possible.   It leads to cleaner script.

---

Suppose A is a subset or equivalent of B.   This means every element of A is an element of B.   It follows that every element of A is an element of the intersection of A and B.   Thus A *is* the intersection of A and B.

Conversely, suppose A is the intersection of A and B.   This means every element of A is an element of B.   Thus A is a subset or equivalent of B.

---

Or symbolically:
$\begin{cases}\begin{align}
A\subseteq B & \iff \forall x\, (x\in A\rightarrow x\in B)
\\ & \iff \forall x\, (x\in A\leftrightarrow x\in A\land x\in B)
\\ & \iff \forall x\, (x\in A\leftrightarrow x\in A\cap B)
\\ & \iff A=A\cap B
\end{align}\end{cases}$

Comment: (+1) Good job focusing the attention on the relevant details! Also, I respect (at least for *this* problem) your desire to avoid "mixing." At this level, it can't hurt to emphasize meaning over notation.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think you're writing a bit too much in your proofs, which is pretty normal for most people starting out in set theory. I was certainly no exception.

> (*) Let $x\in A=A\cap B$. By definition of an intersection, this implies that $x\in B$. Since $x\in A \rightarrow x\in B$, we have shown that $A⊆B$.
>
> (**) Assume that $A⊆B$. We must show that: $A⊆A\cap B$ and $A \cap B ⊆A$ to prove that $A = A\cap B$. Let $x \in A$; by the assmption, $x\in B$. Thus, $x \in A \cap B$. This proves that $A⊆A\cap B$. Now suppose that $x\in A \cap B$. This implies that $x\in A$. Thus, $x\in A\cap B \rightarrow x \in A$ implies $A\cap B $ ⊆ A.

That's it- you're done!

Comment: I would much prefer that my students, especially at this level, won't write $x\in A=A\cap B$, but rather write "$x\in A$, since $A=A\cap B$ we have that $x\in A\cap B$ ..." instead.

Comment: Sorry- I didn't know alethiologist was your student.

Comment: yess this is my very first time in real analysis. I feel so glad that everyone here is really kind and wouldn't mind to lead me to the correct answer. Thank you so much!! (note : i'm not AsafKaragila's student, I'm everyone's student.)

Comment: He's not my student. I was just making that remark, since for first time encounters with set theory, it's better to be more explicit than less explicit. I'm sorry if I somehow confused you like that. :-)

Comment: Oh, haha, okay. Either way, that solution should work.

Comment: It's worth noting that Asaf will not see your comment unless he happens to recheck this particular post. You're getting this notification because this comment was made on your answer. Had Asaf been the only prior commenter on your answer, he would've received a notification of your comment, but alethiologist also commented, so Asaf would never have been notified of your comment. To make sure that somebody is notified of a particular comment, you should use the `@` in front of their username, unless the comment is on their post (Q or A). For example, @AsafKaragila will know about this comment.

Comment: @Cameron, thanks. I did see it though, before the ping. :-) But the general education for proper pinging is good.